# Pesquisa de valores com PHP - É possível?

Tags: php, csv

É possível acessar um arquivo .CSV, capturar um valor e pesquisá-lo em outro arquivo .CSV?!

**Exemplo:**
*Observação: As imagens abaixo são de arquivos .xlsb, mas é só pra demonstração, estou utilizando arquivos .csv*

O código deveria no caso armazenar um valor e o procura em outro arquivo .CSV, no meu caso, seria igual dessas imagens:

https://prnt.sc/goaudl
https://prnt.sc/goau8y

Ele vai procurar o valor "80283022" na planilha "trabalhos", gravá-lo e procurar ele na planilha "itens" e quando achá-lo(na linha 155) vai pegar o valor da coluna G que é "6".

**É possível?!**

Tenho um pequeno código que acessa os arquivos .csv e coleta alguns dados.

```
<?php
$file1 = __DIR__ . '/download/Trabalhos.csv';
$csv1 = file($file1);
foreach ($csv1 as $row1 => $line1) {
    $row1++;
    $column1 = str_getcsv($line1, ';');
    if ($row1 == 2) {
        $column1[6]."<br>";
        $valor1 = $column1[6];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Olá Alex, por favor não use "Trecho de código" (Stack Snippets) com PHP, leia: http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635

Comment: Perdão! Não ocorrerá novamente Guilherme, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz esta função você entra com o arquivo que você quer pesquisar, a coluna onde vai pesquisar o valor e a coluna onde vai se retornado o valor e o valor de pesquisa.

```
<?php
function pesquisaCsv($arquivo, $coluna_pesquisa, $coluna_resultado, $valor){
    if (($handle = fopen($arquivo, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if($data[$coluna_pesquisa] == $valor){
                return $data[$coluna_pesquisa];
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

$file1 = __DIR__ . '/download/Trabalhos.csv';
$csv1 = file($file1);
foreach ($csv1 as $row1 => $line1) {
    $row1++;
    $column1 = str_getcsv($line1, ';');
    if ($row1 == 2) {
        $column1[6]."<br>";
        $valor1 = $column1[6];
        pesquisaCsv('/download/outro_arquivo.csv', 0, 6, $valor1)
    }
}
?>
```